# protect/unprotect connection string in appconfig

Tags: c#, app-config

I am protecting connectionString section in my application. Everything works, but there is one issue. If I terminate my program, than my connectionString section is unprotected. How can I avoid it?
ps: for protection/ unprotection I am using RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider Class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you a *save* method call when you protect/unprotect it. You can get around this by not saving the config file.

Also you should always keep it protected. When you need a clear-text value you un-protect it in memory and use the value (preferably using `SecureString`). Make sure you destroy the unprotected value as soon as you don't need it.

The difference is that the unprotected value only exist in memory of the current process, and never saved back into the config file.

Answer (score 0):

there is a great article about protecting connections string... have a  [look](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/advanced-data-access-scenarios/protecting-connection-strings-and-other-configuration-information-cs)